# How to distinguish numbers from ip addresses in regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

For example, if we look at 5.56 and 183.55.0.144. Basically, when you do something like this `/\d+\.\d+/` it matches 5.56, 189.55 and 0.144. Is there a way to match by regexp only numbers but not ip adresses' parts? I tried to use lookaheads, but I can't figure it out what kind of it should be like...

Here's a set of examples I try with:

1. <some_text> 5.56 <some_text>
2. <some_text> 183.55.0.144 <some_text>
3. 4544445555.6877878487874
4. 1.75.

How to get 1,3 and 4, without parts of 2?

I tried something like:

1. `\d+\.\d+`
2. `\d+\.\d(?!\.)`
3. `(?<!\.)\d+\.\d+` (very close...)
4. `(?<!\.)\d+\.\d(?!\.)`
5. `(?!(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\d+\.\d+(?!\.)\d+` (very close)
6. `\d+\.(?!(?:\.\d+){2})\d+`
7. `(?<!(?:\.\d){2})\d+\.(?!(?:\.\d+){2})\d+`
   And many different forms like these.

Google gives something like these:
`[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+` or `[+-]?[0-9]+[.][0-9]*([e][+-]?[0-9]+)?`
And many other variations. But they are all match parts of ip.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Another way is to replace all ip addresses with some magic replacement, do your number regex, then replace them back

Comment: Tricky! This one almost works but fails spectacularly by not getting the long float and splitting the IP address into tow floats `\b\d+\.\d+(?=.)\b`

Comment: @Andy Ray wow, that looks like the easiest way... =) Thank you.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/8Ena9g/1 doesn't use any lookaheads, just makes sure the "number" isn't surrounded by periods or numbers

Comment: @Andy Ray yup. Seems like it. I tried the same concept myself, but for some reason, I couldn't make it work. xD Thx

Comment: Can you specify what may come before/after the acceptable `N.N` ? The shown examples have spaces, or a period but not followed by a  number (after `N.N`).  That's not all that may be around `N.N`, right?  What else?  (Or, _specifically_, what must not?)

Comment: @zdim Basically, the question is to find all float numbers in the text with IPs.

Comment: "_find all float numbers in the text with IPs_"  -- well, but is `a .12.12 b` OK? How about `a.12.34`?  Etc.  When you say "float" does it mean surrounded by spaces?  Except that it may be followed by `.` (end of sentence)? May it be preceded by `.` (`.1.23` -- not a legitimate float) ?

Comment: Then, are these floats a part of text -- separated by spaces (or ended by punctuation or starting at a beginning of string)?  That would simplify it tremendously. Can they have `+-` in front?

Comment: @zdim nope, in my case there is no need for floats like ".75" or "+50". Just only shown in examples. Regarding the surrounding symbols. They are text, space, period at the end or nothing.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Then I think my post has all of that (as far as I recall my testing) ...?  Another thing -- do you consider Perl code (and using a Perl library), or are you after only a regex alone?

Comment: @zdim I use regex a lot, almost everywhere I can. That's why I'm usually looking for a solution only in terms of regex, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using a library for matching/verifying IP addresses, so to discard such strings, is a reliable way.  But let's try this one for your purpose

```
/(?<!\.[0-9])(?<!\.) ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) (?![0-9]*\.[0-9])/x;
```

It works as asked in the question, and works for a number of other cases that I tested with.

---

With the requirements articulated in comments, we can go a more reliable way: build an alternation pattern with all possibilities

> in my case there is no need for floats like ".75" or "+50".
> Just only shown in examples.
> Regarding the surrounding symbols.
> They are text, space, period at the end or nothing.

First, the regex itself

```
(?: ^ | [a-zA-Z\s] ) ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) (?: [a-zA-Z\s] | (?:\.(?:[^0-9]|$)) | $ )
```

In a Perl program for testing, and laid out for easier reading

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @tt = (                # test strings from the question
    '<some_text> 5.56 <some_text>',
    '<some_text> 183.55.0.144 <some_text>',
    '4544445555.6877878487874',
    '1.75.'
);

push @tt, @ARGV;          # add strings if given on command line

for (@tt) {
    say "--- $_";                 # print current test-string
    say for                       # print captures, one per line
        m{ (?: ^ | [a-zA-Z\s] )   # beginning of string or letter-or-space
           ([0-9]+) \. ([0-9]+)   # decimal number as expected, nums captured 
           (?: [a-zA-Z\s]         # letter-or-space
               | (?: \.           #   or period followed by
                   (?: [^0-9]|$)) #      non-number or end-of-string
               | $ )              #   or end-of-string
         }xg;
}

# The other approach    
#for (@tt) {
#    say for /(?<!\.[0-9])(?<!\.) ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) (?![0-9]*\.[0-9])/xg;
#}
```

I run this with an additional test-string, as

```
> perl prog.pl "a 0.23 is not .230 nor 12.23. But 22.33.44 is a-no"
```

and that prints

```
--- <some_text> 5.56 <some_text>
5
56
--- <some_text> 183.55.0.144 <some_text>
--- 4544445555.6877878487874
4544445555
6877878487874
--- 1.75.
1
75
--- a 0.23 is not .230 nor 12.23. But 22.33.44 is a-no
0
23
12
23
```

Matched are `5.56`, `4544445555.6877878487874`,`1.75.` from the question and `0.23`, `12.23` from the input string, with the pairs of numbers comprising each float captured and printed.

If the float is rather to be captured change `([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)` to `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`.

Comment: This variant seems to have the same matches as mine. Looks ok for my case. Thank you

Comment: For a string `"ah 0.23 is not .230 not 12.23. But 12.23.23 is no"`it prints `0` `23` `12` `23` (so catches `0.23` and `12.23`), but not `.230` -- should it catch that, too? It's a legitimate float (in computing)

Comment: @Incognito Added another way, possible with specific requirements spelled out: form an or-ed pattern of the possibilities.  Tested with your test strings plus an additional string I added, in a Perl program

Answer (score 2):

Another option for the example data might be:

```
(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+\.\d+\b` Match 1+ digits `.` 1+ digits
- `(?!\.\d)` negative lookahead, assert not `.` followed by a digit to the right

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/HExzXN/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookarounds in conjunction with word-boundaries:

```
\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d)
```

or, in place of the last word-boundary, making the dot optional in the lookahead:

```
\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d+(?!\.?\d)
```

or, with perl only, using a possessive quantifier:

```
\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d++(?!\.\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @Andy Ray: `[^\.0-9](\d+(\.\d+)?)[^\.0-9]`
Matches in next cases:

1. <some_text> **5.56** <some_text>
2. <some_text> 183.55.0.144 <some_text>
3. **4544445555.6877878487874**
4. 1.75.
5. 127.0.0.1
6. **555** (Doesn't match if there is nothing at the end of a number )

---

Mine: `(?<!\.)(?:\d+\.)(?!\d+\.\d+)\d+`

1. <some_text> **5.56** <some_text>
2. <some_text> 183.55.0.144 <some_text>
3. **4544445555.6877878487874**
4. **1.75**.
5. 127.0.0.1
6. 555

---

Another way is to replace all ip addresses with some magic replacement, do your number regex, then replace them back (c) @Andy Ray

Comment: @mplungjan when I open your example I see the next regex `(?<!\.)(?:\d+\.)(?!\d+\.\d+)\d+\b\d+\.\d+(?=.)\b`. Mine is `(?<!\.)(?:\d+\.)(?!\d+\.\d+)\d+`