# How to make this Perl regex less greedy (or at least use negation with \Q\E)

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse the following line into 3 variables

```
BS<syntax interpolate='#'> #greeting</syntax>AS
```

I need to capture: `$1 = BS`, `$2 = interpolate='#'`, and `$3 = AS`.

The problem is that with my regex `$2` is `'interpolate='#'>#greeting</syntax'`. Obviously it's matching on the second `>` but nothing I try will convince it to match on the first. The characters `<`, `>` and `syntax` are all referred to as variables in a `%syntax` hash and my regex is

```
$line =~ /(\w+)$syntax{'start'}\Q$syntax{'syntax'}\E\s+(.+?)\Q$syntax{'end'}\E(\w+)/i
```

I have tried using `([^\Q$syntax{'end'}\E]+)` for the second bracket and even `([^\>]+)` and in those cases it doesn't even match. Weirdly there seems no difference at all between `(.+)` and `(.+?)`. Cany anyone solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `.+?` to stop at the first `>` in the shown string, the `\w+` in the pattern `.+?>\w+` needs to match  `#greeting</syntax>AS` -- which has many characters that `\w` doesn't match (space, `#`, `<`, `/`).

One way around that is to list all of those, `[\s#<\/\w]+` (instead of `\w+`).  Another, to use a more permissive pattern instead of `\w`.  I can't tell what is better suited for your problem...

This all holds when `<` (etc) are interpolated from a hash; `\Q`-`\E` aren't needed here.

---

However, if `AS` indeed need be captured, then we need a little more.  Perhaps

```
if ( /(\w+)<syntax \s+ (.+?) > \s+ [\s#\/<\w]+ > (\w+)/ix )
```

or

```
if ( /(\w+)<syntax \s+ (.+?) > \s+ [^>]+ > (\w+)/ix )
```

is suitable (I dropped the use of `%syntax` hash for readability).

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that. .* is actually what I want there I think

Comment: @Maelstrom "_.* is actually what I want there I think_" -- that certainly takes care of it.  Took me a minute to notice, too.  It's a little "hidden" somehow

Comment: @Maelstrom I realize, while this fixed the main problem it still wouldn't capture `AS`.   The rest is simple but I did also add it to the post

Comment: Thanks heaps but unfortunately I misstated my actual problem and it turns out $3 needed everything after the first tag as I'm looping through an array and pushing everything outside of <specifictag> into one of two arrays so .* works for me. Now my only problem is the \n at the end is going missing but google tells me /s will help with that. While I check it out I'll read up on /x in the hopes of one day being able to understand the regexes you just posted.

Comment: @Maelstrom Ah, OK.  Still, I'll leave it so to answer the question as stated (which is rather reasonable, too).  Yes, the `/s` makes `.` also match a newline; that way `.` works with patterns that match text that stretches over multiple lines (in multiline strings).  The `/x` makes it ignore literal spaces in the pattern so one can spread things out for readability.  Then it also ignores newlines and `#`-comments -- so regex can be written over multiple lines and with comments (here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75481733/4653379) I can readily recall)

Comment: But then `.*` with `/s` will scoop up _everything_ that remains.  If  you'd rather get just the one newline then `\n` matches a newline.  So `.*\n`, without `/s`, may work as well -- the `.*` matches all up to the first newline, and then `\n` matches the newline itself.

Comment: (I have to mention: if this is XML then [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) _does_ in the end make it easier.  The docs are spread over multiple sub-packages, I can provide links that summarize that (if you want them))

Comment: Well if you're going to force the confession it's actually a template module that tries to follow the <tag param=value> model of HTML as closely as possible. But before you mention any CPAN modules this is the only one I've found that separates parsing and printing and allows the template writer to modify the syntax. Thanks for the tip on '\n' vs /s. It saved my bacon again. Hopefully. I've been trying to solve the problem of serving a perfect copy of the original template for years now and every newline I add or line counter I increment or decrement breaks something else.

Comment: Hah! I knew it :)  OK then.  I can't preach about template modules, of which there are many, since I've never used one and am blissfully ignorant about 'em.  But if you have to go by hand then details _are_ the thing...

Comment: A few other tidbits, just in case: `/m` treats the string (that regex is applied to) as "multiline" so `^` and `$` match around newlines inside, not only at the beginning and end; and there is also `\z`, subtly different from `$` in terms of how it treats the newline character itself.  Finally: While the docs may not be all that friendly I found that once one gets comfortable with them then that's all you need; it's [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) and [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) and [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash)

Comment: Thanks. I'm back on the grind now but I'll re-read those docs next weekend. And adding the \n to the regexp has worked a treat, allowed me to remove superfluous inserts and simplified my code to the point I can actually understand it. Now it's reproducing the source so perfectly that <loop>\nline\n</loop> is grabbing both \n and double-spacing the lines which is annoyingly counter intuitive but it's a lot easier to deal with than having newlines added to my text boxes that can't be removed.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`.

```perl
my ( $B, $E, $S ) = map quotemeta, @syntax{qw( start end syntax )};

m{
   (\w+)
   $B $S \s+ ( (?: (?!$E). )+ ) $E
   (?: (?! $B | $E ). )*
   $B /$S $E
   (\w+)
}xsi
```

I doubt the benefit of abstracting away the syntax elements. If you hardcode them, it becomes:

```perl
m{
   (\w+)
   <syntax \s+ ( [^>]+ ) >
   [^<>]*
   </syntax>
   (\w+)
}xsi
```

Notice that I avoided the non-greedy modifier isn't safe. It's not safe to use. It doesn't prevent you from ending up matching way more than you desire.

Doing this using regex is extremely fragile. A proper parser will pay for itself time and time again. And you wouldn't need our help writing complex regex patterns.

Comment: In this case the benefit of abstracting away the syntax elements is the end user will be able to modify them using said syntax tag. In any other case though I'm sure you'd be right.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'd recommend here.

First, let the sub-patterns in your hash decide what they need to escape. I can't see your hash, but I suspect that you are inadvertently escaping regex characters that should be regex characters.

Second, don't use numbered captures when you are interpolating other patterns. If they themselves have captures, you'll throw off your numbering. Instead, used named captures:

```
use v5.10;

my %syntax = (
    start  => qr/ < syntax \s+  /x,
    syntax => qr/ (?<interpolate>interpolate = '.+?') > /x,
    end    => qr| < / syntax > |x,
    );

my $string = "BS<syntax interpolate='#'> #greeting</syntax>AS";

$string =~ /
    (?<pre>\w+)
    $syntax{'start'}
    $syntax{'syntax'}
    \s+
    (?<middle>.+?)
    $syntax{'end'}
    (?<post>\w+)
    /x;

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( \%+ );
```

Here's the output. Grab the values out of the hash as needed:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'interpolate' => 'interpolate=\'#\'',
          'middle' => '#greeting',
          'post' => 'AS',
          'pre' => 'BS'
        };
```

But, if you have these simple XML/HTML looking fragments, a DOM can pick out parts that you need:

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $string = "BS<syntax interpolate='#'> #greeting</syntax>AS";
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($string);

my $start = $dom->root->descendant_nodes->[0];
say "START: $start";

my $attr = 'interpolate';
my $stuff = $dom->at('syntax')->attr($attr);
say "ATTR: $attr $stuff";

my $middle = $dom->at('syntax')->text;
say "MIDDLE: $middle";

my $start = $dom->root->descendant_nodes->[-1];
say "END: $start";
```

Here's all the stuff you wanted, but you probably want to trim some whitespace:

```
START: BS
ATTR: interpolate #
MIDDLE:  #greeting
END: AS
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on named captures, that's wild.